# Alternative to React.useState => Object useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

So for people who use `React.useState` it's really a pain to create multi `useState` with `[value, setValue]` so I have been thinking what if we could create something like `object.useState` where you can have an object in `useState` and simple assign `value` and it will trigger the default behavior of `setValue`.

And this is what I came with, see here on [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@alentoma/usestatealternative).

**Use example**

```js
  const item = objectUseState({
    counter: 0,
    counter2: 0,
    text: "",
    item: { ItemCounter: 0 },
  });
  
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('counter is Changed');
    console.log(item);
  }, [item.counter]);
  
  
  return (<Text onPress={()=> item.counter+=1}> {item.counter} </Text>)
```

There is some limitation that I encounter. And that is the array values, I can't use methods like `push` and so on.

Comment: What is wrong with using an object on useState?

Comment: Or use `useReducer`

Comment: @KyleLambert my example is a lot more easer and less code then reducer. that is why `useState` exist.

Comment: `useReducer` is preferred for managing complex state like an object, or if your state changes depend on previous state. It's also easier to test. Your example doesn't have a setter function either, you're just mutating an object.

Comment: exactly `useReducer` is used for more complex thing. and mine is used for the easier objects. that was the idea my friend. Now when you assign `item.counter+=1` in the background the setter of the `React.useState` is triggered. So I am using setter. you can see that useEffect is triggered

Comment: Hi. Your question should be closed, but your approach make me think about the `immer` library used in `redux-toolkit`, I already took the same approach in my own library `reactizy`. And subjectively, I like this, but In your case, it's only available for objects I can see... If you succeed to this issue, I'll check your code, it's interresting.

Comment: @BENARDPatrick Yes it is only for objects as using `string, number ` etc should be used with the default `react.useState` instead.